# How to filter an android custom listview?

Tags: android, listview, filter

I have a custom **ListView** and I want to filter it. It has 4 or 5 columns and want to filter it on one column to show all result of a search filter.
When I used:

```
((Filterable) FicheClient1.this.adapter).getFilter().filter(cs);
```

it showed me double and filtering in all the row .

My **ListView**:

```
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> clientList =  controller.getAllClient();
    if(clientList.size()!=0) {
        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override 
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                clientId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.clientId);
                nom = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
                emailtext = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.emailficheclient);
                String valclientId = clientId.getText().toString(); 
                String nameString = nom.getText().toString();
                String emailString = emailtext.getText().toString();
                cli.setNamelist(nameString);
                cli.setClientId(valclientId);
                cli.setEmailString(emailtext.getText().toString());
                Intent  objIndent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),EditNouveauClient.class);
                objIndent.putExtra("clientId", valclientId);
                objIndent.putExtra("nom", nameString);
                startActivity(objIndent);
                FicheClient1.this.finish();
            }
        });
        adapter = new SimpleAdapter( FicheClient1.this,clientList, R.layout.client_item_row, new String[] { "clientId","civilite"
                ,"name","prenom","naissance","email"}, 
                new int[] {R.id.clientId, R.id.civilite, R.id.name, R.id.prenom, R.id.naissance, R.id.emailficheclient}); 
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

**SearchFilter**:

```
inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3
        ((Filterable) FicheClient1.this.adapter).getFilter().filter(cs);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For the filter, suppose your edittext name is `searchbar`, and adapter name is `adpater`

```
    serchbar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text

            adpater.getFilter().filter(cs.toString());
         }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
        }

    });
```

your filter in `adpater` will be..

```
/*** filter text data ***/


    public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter filter = new Filter() {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results) {

            menuItems = (   ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) results.values; // has the filtered values
            notifyDataSetChanged();  // notifies the data with new filtered values
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();        // Holds the results of a filtering operation in values
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> FilteredArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            if (mDisplayedValues == null) {
                mDisplayedValues = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(menuItems); // saves the original data in mOriginalValues
            }

            /********
             * 
             *  If constraint(CharSequence that is received) is null returns the mOriginalValues(Original) values
             *  else does the Filtering and returns FilteredArrList(Filtered)  
             *
             ********/
            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {

                // set the Original result to return  
                results.count = mDisplayedValues.size();
                results.values = mDisplayedValues;
            } else {
                constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                for (int i = 0; i < mDisplayedValues.size(); i++) {
                    String data =      mDisplayedValues.get(i).get(ServerConstant.key_event_name);
                    Log.v("publish result", data);
                    if (data.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString())) {

                        Log.i("publish result match",constraint.toString() +"hiiiii " + data);
                        FilteredArrList.add(mDisplayedValues.get(i));
                    }
                }
                // set the Filtered result to return
                results.count = FilteredArrList.size();
                results.values = FilteredArrList;
            }
            return results;
        }
    };
    return filter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an `HashMap` for the `ListView` you need the implement `Filterable` interface for `ListView`'s adapter and override `getFilter()` in this method you need to write the logic for filtering the  list.

for example :

```
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter filter = new Filter() {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results) {

            menuItems = (   ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) results.values; // has the filtered values
            notifyDataSetChanged();  // notifies the data with new filtered values
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();        // Holds the results of a filtering operation in values
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> FilteredArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            if (mDisplayedValues == null) {
                mDisplayedValues = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(menuItems); // saves the original data in mOriginalValues
            }

            /********
             * 
             *  If constraint(CharSequence that is received) is null returns the mOriginalValues(Original) values
             *  else does the Filtering and returns FilteredArrList(Filtered)  
             *
             ********/
            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {

                // set the Original result to return  
                results.count = mDisplayedValues.size();
                results.values = mDisplayedValues;
            } else {
                constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                for (int i = 0; i < mDisplayedValues.size(); i++) {
                    String data =      mDisplayedValues.get(i).get(ServerConstant.key_event_name);
                    Log.v("publish result", data);
                    if (data.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString())) {

                        Log.i("publish result match",constraint.toString() +"hiiiii " + data);
                        FilteredArrList.add(mDisplayedValues.get(i));
                    }
                }
                // set the Filtered result to return
                results.count = FilteredArrList.size();
                results.values = FilteredArrList;
            }
            return results;
        }
    };
    return filter;
}
```

for more details [Click here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filterable.html)